# AppleScript Error Code -1700

Tags: unicode, applescript

This is the error that pops up when I try my script out:

> `Script Error ---- Can’t make {button returned:"Enter", text returned:"testing"} into type Unicode text.`

I'm trying to have users enter a Username so that they that have their *Documents* folder be linked to a file server.

I have that part separate but now on this part of having the user input their username so when I have `ln -s /Volumes/Drive/Documents Documents` the username will automatically pull from the script and input it by itself so the *Documents* folder and File server could be linked.

Basically trying to make it to where the user doesn't have to go into the terminal and link the two together. I'm not sure why the error code is popping up other than it is probably having to deal with the set Username part of the script so not completely sure.

```
set Username to (display dialog "Enter your NetID Username" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Enter"} default button 2)

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "'ln -s /Volumes/Drive/Documents Documents'" & Username
end tell
return input
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> Can’t make {button returned:"Enter", text returned:"testing"} into type Unicode text.

is pretty clear.

`display dialog` returns a record, not a string so you have to write

```
set Username to text returned of (display dialog "Enter your NetID Username" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Enter"} default button 2)
```

Or if you need to handle the button and the returned text write

```
set {button returned:buttonReturned, text returned:textReturned} to display dialog "Enter your NetID Username" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Enter"} default button 2
```

Comment: this work perfectly!! Thank you, I'm teaching myself this language and just trying to figure out the tips and tricks to it. Again thank you very much